# 'cluster_enabled yes' Bad directive or wrong number of arguments REDIS

Tags: redis

Hello in ubuntu while trying to run this redis syntax I received the following errors:

```
davy@davy-Aspire-E5-476G:~/7002$ redis-server n2_redis.conf &
[1] 7118
davy@davy-Aspire-E5-476G:~/7002$ 
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 6.0.16) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 2
 >>> 'cluster_enabled yes'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
^C
[1]+  Exit 1                  redis-server n2_redis.conf
```

Any idea how to fix the error messages?

```
  davy@davy-Aspire-E5-476G:~/7002$ head n2_redis.conf
  port 7002
  cluster_enabled yes
  cluster_config_file nodes.conf
  cluster_node_timeout 5000
  appendonly yes
```

Comment: what's the output of `head n2_redis.conf`?

Comment: Since I unable to go to the next line in comment, I updated the answer in the first post.

Comment: ah, looks like a simple typo; it should be `cluster-enabled` https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/#create-and-use-a-redis-cluster

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the [Redis configuration file example](https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/), you should have dashes `-` instead of underscores `_` for all of your configurations:

```
port 7002
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed the file into what you suggested then:  davy@davy-Aspire-E5-476G:~/7002$ redis-server n2_redis.conf

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 6.0.16) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 4
>>> 'cluster-node-time-out 5000'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments

Comment: @DavyYG It should be `cluster-node-timeout`.